# Unable to initialize main class selenium.Test

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have installed java and eclipse, and downloaded the JARS and placed them in the right directory as it should be. Below is my script:

```
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\softwares\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");   
    }

}
```

And I get the below error:

Error: Unable to initialize main class selenium.Test
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
How can I solve this error?

Comment: did you check the classpath settings on eclipse?

Comment: seems like the Selenium JAR file is missing from the project.  Did you add that?

Comment: How can I add it? Can you please explain.